# Phaser Game with multi interfaces best practice

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I need help with Phaser, i know that using this code :

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1280, 730, Phaser.CANVAS, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
```

i can start a phaser game, but i need to know the best practice using many interfaces. Example when i have 5 interfaces do i have to write this code in each one?
Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "interfaces" you mean scenes or states of the game? When you first start one gets used to coding in the same .js file but when the project is extended I have read that a good practice is to organize the code in states, and this is advisable, documentate [here](http://perplexingtech.weebly.com/game-dev-blog/using-states-in-phaserjs-javascript-game-developement) is very simple :)